# Can you buy a property on your next roll?

Tags: monopoly

Let’s say a player rolls and he lands on Park Avenue but doesn’t buy it. On his next turn before he rolls Can he buy that property?  Or does he lose this opportunity?

Answer (score 15):

No, that player may not buy that property. That property should have immediately gone to auction when the player opted not to buy it on their turn. Thus when they start their next turn, the property is already owned.

From the [Monopoly Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf):

> BUYING PROPERTY: Whenever you land on an unowned property you
> may buy that property from the Bank at its printed price. You receive the
> Title Deed card showing ownership; place it faceup in front of you.
> **If you do not wish to buy the property, the Banker sells it at auction
> to the highest bidder**. The buyer pays the Bank the amount of the bid
> in cash and receives the Title Deed card for that property. Any player,
> including the one who declined the option to buy it at the printed
> price, may bid. Bidding may start at any price.

Comment: Technically, it's possible that noone bid on it at all. But not realistically.

Comment: I mean, not when you could literally pick it up for a dollar and immediately mortgage it and forget it for free money.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I would love to play Monopoly with people who wouldn't even pay $1 for Park Avenue.

Comment: I think it's still worth covering the "what if no one buys it" case, since the true governing action here is that buying a property is an event triggered by landing on its space after a move (otherwise the person buying it out from under you might be able to charge you rent, or you'd have to draw two Chance Cards on a Chance space, etc.).

Comment: I guess also, to be technical, the fact that the property is auctioned off means that the player can indeed buy the property at the start of the turn - they just have to buy it from the person who bid on it, which either of them might not agree to, or which may happen at a very different price than what the first player was intending.

Comment: @TheHansinator I think the rules are pretty clear about how the game is played. You start a turn by rolling the dice and moving the number of spaces. There's no option to buy before rolling. In addition, you can only buy a property _when_ you land on it.

Comment: @TheHansinator If you want to be technical, you can only buy from the bank when you land. You can bid on an auction or trade with another player.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Before you roll, you can trade with other players and buy houses/hotels. That's why I (admittedly, cheekily) say you could buy the property at the start of the next turn - you buy it from the person who bought it at auction.

Comment: @TheHansinator "Before you roll, you can trade with other players and buy houses/hotels." That's only in some editions, hence the confusion I think.

Comment: @TheHansinator Sure, but it's a trade, not a buy. <3